# Import json array of objects to Elastic Search App

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have following sample json data with structure

```
 [{
        "URL": "http://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-bluebreeze-le3/menu",
        "_id": "55f14313c7447c3da7052518",
        "address": "56 Bonney Road",
        "address line 2": "Leicester",
        "name": "Blue Breeze Fish Bar",
        "outcode": "LE3",
        "postcode": "9NG",
        "rating": 5.5,
        "type_of_food": "Fish \u0026 Chips"
    },
    {
        "URL": "http://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-bluebreeze-le3/menu",
        "_id": "55f14313c7447c3da7052519",
        "address": "56 Bonney Road",
        "address line 2": "Leicester",
        "name": "Blue Breeze Fish Bar",
        "outcode": "LE3",
        "postcode": "9NG",
        "rating": 5.5,
        "type_of_food": "Fish \u0026 Chips"
    }, 
...... and so on thousands of objects
]
```

So i am trying to import this json data to Elastic Search App cluster i created... But i get error in all documents as follows

```
Indexing Summary
Something went wrong. Please address the errors and try again.
2548 documents with errors...
```

they didn't give any error details... just said listed all my objects with "semicolon highlighted"...

Can anyone tell me why am i not able to upload the data?

Comment: How are you importing the data into Elasticsearch? Could you please write the exact query with maybe just a sample document.

Comment: Also, not sure if you are doing this but Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document.

Comment: yeah I figured it out... the naming convention of fields doesn't allow uppercase letters or underscore in the beginning.... Now i can add the data after following those conventions...